# How to run different React folders in same development server?

Tags: next.js

I created two Next.js directories in the same parent directory and when I try to run them, I need to run them separately. For example, I run them one by one in servers 3000 and 3001. And when I try to link one another, for example with the block of code down below, I need to link to 3001 but I want them to work in the same server. How can I achieve this?

package.json file in landing-page folder:

```json
{
  "name": "simple-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "landing-page",
    "terms"
  ]
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.14",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "next": "^13.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.9",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

footer.tsx file in landing-page folder:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3001" className="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 hover:underline transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
  Terms
</a>
```

I tried linking to `"/terms"`, `"http://localhost:3000/terms"` and couple of more lines of code like these ones but they all ended with failure.